# Container's Borders are not uniform

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, border

Even with the same width given to the borders of a container they don't look like they have the same width, just like the image below ( Tested on a real device,Model Name - Samsung S9 ) : -

[image]

Along with this, the borders seem to look different on different devices as in the following image ( Tested on a real device,Model Name - Samsung a31 ) : -

[image]

In the above image also the borders do not look that they have the same width

Code which I used : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  left: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the question here? if the boxes are not the same width or if the borders are not equals?

Comment: Border dont look of equal of width , even though they all have the same width, In my first image , you can see one border looks thicker than others.

Comment: what's the flutter version you are using?

Comment: also can you try this value in your BorderSide? `strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignInside,`

Comment: @diegoveloper, I will try. I am using flutter 3.10.1

Comment: @diegoveloper, even with strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignInside, still border dont look equal

Comment: does this only happen of you samsung devices? I tried on iOS simulator and it works fine.

Comment: @diegoveloper, On other devices  like OnePlus same thing happens, also on some devices its works fine but on most of the devices it does not.

Comment: This is one of those “not your problem” problems.  If you defined the border to be uniform, then what happens after that is out of your control.  You cant be responsible for predicting the misbehavior of every existing device and/or the flutter renderer.  Im guessing the issue has to do with rounding error and/or anti aliasing.

Comment: @NerdyBunz but  every problem has a solution. If this is a bug then it can be fixed.

Comment: Are you asking about width (Thickness) of border or length?

Comment: @UpendraShah, I am pertaining to Width(Thickness) of border

Comment: @Ramji as per Dart Doc if you passes width 0.0 to 1.0 than it means it takes min 1px and that might double-hit pixels, giving it a slightly darker/lighter result. so if you want proper result than pass width as 1 or more px. I have also added answer you can get more details from that.

Comment: @UpendraShah, the brighter/thicker effect should be applied on all borders of container and not just only on few borders.

Comment: @Ramji I have added a comment on my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the difference in the screen DPI(Dots per inch) which leads to the difference in layouts in different devices. It also differs for an iOS device and an Android device with the same screen height.

So, I basically use the [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) package from Flutter for the UI responsiveness. Also, it is very simple to use.

Configuration:
Wrap MaterialApp with Sizer widget:

```
Sizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp();
      }
 )
```

Example:
For widgets:

```
 Container(
  width: 20.w,    //It will take a 20% of screen width
  height:30.h     //It will take a 30% of screen height
)
```

For fonts:

```
Text(
  'Sizer',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp),
);
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: I have already tried this but still, in some devices, borders look thicker than others.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have widths that are decimal. Personally I don't get why it's even allowed but I also experience that it often gives issues. Just define all those widths that you have as `0.5` and change them to `1`. It doesn't make much sense anyway to have something be half a pixel

Comment: but remember that 0.5 is a logical pixel which has nothing to do with a philosophical one

Comment: Yes, you are right @Ivo, that decimal is the root problem and I knew about it before posting my question. Setting the width to 1 makes my app look completely different. So I can not do that.

Comment: @pskink, what do you mean by "philosophical one" ?

Comment: @Ramji physical of course :-) those virtual keyboards on smartphones sometimes are too "smart"

Answer (score 2):

This is because the width value is not the same on all screen, ex: if the device width is 500 and your container width is 250 that mean is equal to 50% of the screen but with different screen widths for example tablet is 700 width screen then your 250 container width is no Longer 50%,
To fix this I wish to use my package [screentasia](https://pub.dev/packages/screentasia) it's simply the best flutter package to deal with all screens.
In this line

```
bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
```

for example, you can use Screentasia with an extension like this

```
bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5.w, color: Colors.black),
```

Now your goal is done.

Comment: My question is regarding the container border's width not the width of container

Comment: The same concept work on border width, you can try and check the result, I hope the package is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

As per document on [Dart BorderSide Width](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderSide/width.html)

> The width of this side of the border, in logical pixels.
>
> Setting width to 0.0 will result in a hairline border. This means that
> the border will have the width of one physical pixel. Hairline
> rendering takes shortcuts when the path overlaps a pixel more than
> once. This means that it will render faster than otherwise, but it
> might double-hit pixels, giving it a slightly darker/lighter result.

**Hairline** is defined as "the thinnest continuous frame." This essentially means it will always be one physical pixel, and not be defined by logical pixels.

from above we can conclude that you are setting width 0.5 pixel it means it might double-hit pixels, so it gives slightly darker/lighter result. So I suppose for test purpose pass width of 2 or more pixel then compare it will not give slightly darker/lighter result.

Comment: Even if there are double hit pixels , it should have effect on all border width and not on few. In my case , few borders look alike and few do not.

Comment: Yes, that can. You can read **it might double-hit pixels** terms and your are using 10 border sides so there can be few border look alike and few not.

Comment: All right with your answer we understood what the problem is but how can we solve it ?

Comment: > Option 1: Just try If you have only three containers then on first and last container add Border.all and in middle border side top and bottom.
> Option 2: Increase border width.

But I am not sure it will fix your issues because you have test case and device.

Comment: Options 1 didn't work.  I cant work with Option since increasing border makes the page look completely different.

Comment: But you can't assign width less than 1px.

Comment: I don't have any other option but using 0.5 for border width.

Answer (score 1):

it could be due to the device pixel density. To ensure consistent border widths across devices, you can calculate the pixel value based on the device's pixel density.
try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red[100],
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  left: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[100],
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange[100],
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(
                      width: (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio),
                      color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: I implemented what you suggested but the value of (0.5 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio) is 1.3 which makes the border thicker than what I want, so I just decreased its value to 0.2 then multiplied by devicePixelRatio the value is 0.525 which makes the border look thin which I want in my app but then problem still remains the same , borders dont look similiar.

Comment: The reason for the varying appearance of the border on different devices is due to differences in device resolution and pixel density. Consider the scenario of comparing an older 720p monitor with a high-resolution 4K screen, and you will grasp the concept.

Comment: I was not addressing this in my comment. What I meant is that in a certain device for example Samsung S9 , the borders of containers itself do not look of equal width even after using devicePixelRatio. I understood the concept that border thickness will differ from device to device because of devicePixelRatio but in the device itself borders are not looking uniformed

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure it's because your borders touch each other so you have an illusion that they are thicker that they should be.

Can you try this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  left: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  left: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange[100],
                border: const Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  left: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: It didnt make any difference, still few border are bigger in width than others

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter, logical pixel values are used instead of physical pixels. On screens with higher pixel densities, a border of 1 logical pixel could be less than 1 physical pixel
Like this:

```
double pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
double borderWidth = 1 * pixelRatio;
```

Your _BoxState class should Like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double pixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
    double borderWidth = 1 * pixelRatio;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red[100],
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                  left: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green[100],
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange[100],
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                  top: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                  right: BorderSide(width: borderWidth, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: In my device when giving borders the value of (1 * pixelRatio) then border width is actually 3 which is almost 2.5 times greater than what I want. When I use (0.2 *pixelRatio), the border width is 0.5, giving the same output, which is border not looking like they have equal width.

Comment: You can try with the fixed with like:
double borderWidth = 0.5;

Comment: Did that but still same output

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code to see if it gives desired result. If yes, I will explain the logic in edit

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
              left: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
              top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
              right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
            )),
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.red[100]!,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
              top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
              right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
            )),
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.green[100]!,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
              top: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
              right: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Colors.black),
            )),
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.orange[100]!,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul suggesting this approach however even with this method. Borders still appear to have different width.

Comment: Can you try adding clip=Clip.hardedge?

Comment: I thought this might work but it did not.

Answer (score 0):

try to use **MediaQuery.of(context).size.width** to get the screen width and then calculating **containerSize** as a quarter (0.25) of that width. This ensures that the containers' sizes adjust based on the screen width.

To make the borders more consistent, use **Border.all** instead of defining individual BorderSide for each side of the container. This gives you all the borders the same width and colors, reducing the uneven appearance.

Feel free to adjust the borderWidth value to your liking for thicker or thinner borders. This way, your containers should look much better and more uniform on various devices.

Comment: I cannot use Border.all since it will overlap the Container and also even with MediaQuery it still makes borders uneven

Comment: in that case use margin and padding with each of the container like this     
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),

Comment: are you also getting this info from chatgpt like you now-deleted answer?

Comment: No, actually i wrote solution on my notepad then paste it here when I'm going to paste here there's some issue on my laptop may be some of its text missing so i type it by myself by modifying my reply i hope you understand the issue.

Comment: @SyedNaseebAli, if I add margin or padding then I wont get the desired layout. I want container to be juxtaposed with each other.

Comment: So then wrap the each container with positioned

Comment: @SyedNaseebAli, I am not able to understand, can you add a small example of that code.

Comment: @Ramji here is example from my code
       **Positioned(
                          left: 0,
                          top: 0,

                          child: Container(
                            width: 335,
                            height: 92,
                            decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                        
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),**

Comment: Understood but still media query does not solve the problem. Border width still look unequal.

Comment: @Ramji bro just give position to each container  make container as a child inside the position before that add left, right ,top, and bottom.it will resolve your problem

Comment: Code which you have added in comment does not even have borders.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).